# JavaScript rounding to negative decimal places like Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, rounding

I am trying to round a number in JavaScript to match the following Excel style rounding.

**Excel:**

```
=ROUND(123456,-1)
```

which outputs

```
123460
```

How can I get JavaScript to round to negative decimal places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function round(x, places)
{
    var shift = Math.pow(10, places);
    return Math.round(x * shift) / shift;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't start a function on the next line, start it on the same line as the declaration.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: What do you mean?

Comment: The upper `{` needs to go on the same line as `function round(...)`. I can't exactly demonstrate, since comments don't allow linebreaks.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: No it doesn't.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: No it doesn't. It is simply a matter of personal preference. I prefer it this way.

Comment: A function requires a block. The interpreter won't ever assume that a blockless function is a valid statement, unlike a argument less return.

Answer (score 0):

[Formula.js](http://stoic.com/formula/) implements all Math functions offered by Microsoft Excel 2013, including ROUND.